# Json data visualization in Reactjs with Chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in reactjs. Currently I'm developing an app which shows json COVID-19 api data into visualization using chartjs but it not visualize the data. I tried everything but it not working.

**Here is my source code.**

App Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Chart from "./Chart";

const App = () => {
  const [chart, setChart] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        'https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/spain'
      );

      setChart({
        labels: [Object.keys(res.data.timeline.cases)],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Covid-19",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: "butt",
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: "miter",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: Object.values(res.data.timeline.cases)
          }
        ]
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Chart data={chart} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

'and this is Chart component'

import React from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

const Chart = ({ data }) => {

  console.log(data);

  return <Line data={data} options={{ responsive: true, height: '600px', width: "600px" }} />;
};

export default Chart;
```

When I open browser it shows the values on X and Y axis but not visualize it. This is my browser image:

[image: browser image]

**And this is [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-neumann-53lh8)**

Comment: This is a duplicate of your preceding question [Data Visualization in ReactJs with ChartJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933835/data-visualization-in-reactjs-with-chartjs)

Comment: It looks like you asked a question, adjusted the code a bit, copy and pasted the descriptive text into a new question, and then pasted the new code. Since the questions are identical they must be treated as duplicates.

Comment: Incidentally, "not working plz help me" is a good way to get _any_ question closed. It is not a useful problem report. Please use real English words, don't beg, state what you are trying to do, what actually happened, and what you think the problem might be. A good rule is, if you find yourself saying "it does not work", **remove it from the question** and describe instead what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `App.js` file under `setChart({ .. })`,

Change:

```
labels: [Object.keys(res.data.timeline.cases)]
```

**to:**

```
labels: Object.keys(res.data.timeline.cases)
```

As you are already receiving the data as a string array, you can directly assign `Object.keys(res.data.timeline.cases)` to `labels` key.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Chart from "./Chart";

const App = () => {
  const [chart, setChart] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/pakistan`
      );

      setChart({
        labels: Object.keys(res.data.timeline.cases),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Covid-19",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: "butt",
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: "miter",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: Object.values(res.data.timeline.cases)
          }
        ]
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Chart data={chart} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

> [**Forked Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-hofstadter-9yrof)